# Concentration inequality of weighted sum of random variables given a tail inequality

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, probability-inequalities

I'm reading [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199535256) on concentration inequalities and I'm trying to solve all of the exercises in the book. The following problem is from the book which I couldn't manage to solve. I have also posted it on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829508/concentration-inequality-of-weighted-sum-of-random-variables-given-a-tail-inequa) a while ago, but I received no response, yet. I'd appreciate it if anyone can give me a hint for solving this problem.

> **Probelm :** Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots ,X_n$ be iid copies of a real random variable $X$
>   that for some $p\geq 1$ obeys
>
> \begin{align*} \mathbb{P}\left(\left\vert X\right\vert > u\right)&
>  \leq \exp\left(-u^p\right), \end{align*}
>
> for all $u>0$. For any $s\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and with
>   $q$ denoting the conjugate of $p$ (i.e., $1/p+1/q=1$) prove that
>
> \begin{align*} \mathbb{P}\left(Z:=\sum _{i=1}^n s_i X_i > t \right)&\le L
>  \exp\left(-\frac{1}{L}\min \left(\frac{t^2}{\left\Vert
>  s\right\Vert_2^2},\frac{t^p}{\left\Vert
>  s\right\Vert_q^p}\right)\right), \end{align*} 
>   where $L>0$ is a
>   constant that only depends on $p$, but not $n$.

Answer (score 3):

Here's some work. I don't think this counts as a complete answer, though. Sorry.

First,
$$
\left|\sum_i s_iX_i\right| \le \sum_i|s_i X_i| \le \left(\sum_i |s_i|^q\right)^{1/q}\left(\sum_i |X_i|^p \right)^{1/p},
$$
by the triangle inequality and Holder's inequality.

Taking this, 
\begin{align*}
P(|Z|>t) &\le P\left( \sum_i |X_i|^p  > t^p\left(\sum_i |s_i|^q\right)^{-p/q}\right) \\
&= P\left( \sum_i |X_i|^p  > \frac{t^p}{ \left\Vert
 s\right\Vert_q^p }\right) .
\end{align*}

I don't know how to sharpen it with the minumum, though. I tried using the fact that $P(\max_i |X_i| \le t) = P(|X_i|\le t)^n$ and the complement rule to get:
$$
P\left( \sum_i |X_i|^p  > \frac{t^p}{ \left\Vert
 s\right\Vert_q^p }\right) \le 
 P\left( \max_i |x_i|^q  > \frac{t^p}{ n \left\Vert
 s\right\Vert_q^p }\right) \le 1 - \left[1 - \exp\left(-\left\{\frac{t^p}{ n \left\Vert
 s\right\Vert_q^p }\right\}^p \right) \right]^n.
$$
Not sure though.